# Determine the value of K for the graph?

Tags: probability

I am studying for a final and I am reviewing material on an exam from a previous semester. I am having trouble with solving the problem in the picture. I had to take a pic to preserve the graph in the question. Which is the part of the problem that I am having the most trouble. I am used to seeing these questions presented numerically but the graph has thrown me.

[image]

I know that to determine the  probability of the events occurring is the area under the curve. However this question is not asking that. It wants me to determine the value K. I am completely lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area under the curve of $f(x)$ is $1$ by the definition of a density function.

So, calculate the area under the curve of $f(x)$, and then set it equal to $1$ and solve for $K$.

Comment: there are 3 triangles here and $K$ is the maximum value, the y-coordinate of these 3 vertex. The total area in this case is just $\frac {3K} {2}$. I think the reciprocal case only holds for the uniform distribution in general where the area under the curve is a rectangle.